# Solve nonlinear, forced and damped Duffing oscillator

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a Duffing type equation by using Van Der Paul's method:

\begin{align}
\ddot{x} + \omega^2 x + 2 \gamma \dot{x} + \beta x^3 = f \cos(\Omega t)  
\end{align}

with $$x(t) = Re[A(t) \exp(i \omega_0 t)]$$ and $$A(t) = a(t) \exp(i \phi(t)),$$ where $a(t), \phi(t)$ are slowly changing variables. So, I get the following system of differential equations:

\begin{align}
\dot{a} & =  -\gamma a +\dfrac{f}{2 \omega_0} \sin(\Psi), \\
\dot{\Psi} &= \delta + \dfrac{3 \beta a^2}{8 \omega_0} - \dfrac{f}{2 \omega_0 a} \cos(\Psi),
\end{align}

where $\gamma, \delta = \Omega - \omega_0 \ll 1, \beta, \omega_0$ are parameters and $\Psi = \delta t - \phi$. Can I solve this somehow? I need to get the equation of motion $x(t)$ corresponding to given initial conditions.

Without 'forcing term' it's easy to integrate the system and find both $a(t), \Psi(t)$.
But I need to take the 'force' into account. And I can square both equations to get rid of sine and cosine.

Here is solution for $f = 0$. Dashed line is numerical solution and solid line is analytical solution.
[image: numerical (dashed) and analytical solutions for f = 0]

And here is the numerical solution for small $f \ll 1$:

[image]

I want to try to find an approximate expression for the equation of motion $x(t)$, but I don't yet understand how to deal with $\sin(\Psi)$ and $\cos(\Psi)$.

Can I somehow find out the Chirikov criterion for resonance overlap?

Comment: Can I somehow find out the Chirikov criterion for resonance overlap?